ZeroDivisionError: integer modulo by zero
I was trying to create a simple python code for finding HCF of two numbers using Euclid's method
a = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
b = int(input('Enter the second number: '))
 while a != b:
   rem = int(a) % int(b)
   a = b
   b = rem
print('The HCF is', a)

and I got a error like
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\HCF.py", line 4, in <module>
     rem = int(a) % int(b)
           ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
  ZeroDivisionError: integer modulo by zero


if you just want to get the greatest common divisor, there is math.gcd(a, b). If you want to reinvent the wheel in order to get a better understanding, feel free to ignore this comment

@Jenson If you have a new issue then post a new question rather than editing this one, I'll roll it back to the original question you had.

The loop condition should be b != 0.

Yes, I must seen it before
